# drupal Webform HTML Email hooks

Tags: html, email, drupal, hook, drupal-webform

I'm trying to send a thank you email to the user submitting the form in HTML.
I found out by using a hook in my template.php file like this works to set the header correctly:

```
function mythemename_webform_mail_headers($form_values, $node, $sid) {
  $headers = array(
    'Content-Type'  => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed; delsp=yes',
    'X-Mailer'      => 'Drupal Webform (PHP/'. phpversion() .')',
  );

  return $headers;
}
```

This works freat for the "Thank You" email.
The email that the site admin gets with the form results is also html, but it's not converting newlines to breaks in this email. I can't figure out how to use a hook for this, so I had to edit the webform.module file and do this:

```
function webform_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  $message['headers'] = array_merge($message['headers'], $params['headers']);
  $message['subject'] = $params['subject'];
  //$message['body'][] = drupal_wrap_mail($params['message']); // replaced this with line below
  $message['body'][] = nl2br(drupal_wrap_mail($params['message']));
}
```

Can this be done with a hook in template.php?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`hook_mail_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_mail_alter/6) to edit mails created with [`hook_mail`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_mail/6), which is what webform uses.

Comment: I tried this but it's not working: function mythemename_mail_alter(&$message) { if ($message['id'] == 'webform_18') { $message['body'][] = nl2br($message['body']); } }

Answer (score 0):

You can't use hook_mail_alter() in a theme, only in a custom module.

Answer (score 0):

Old topic but still usefull I guess. On the webform module's edit page there is a option/fieldset with  additional processing:

```
<?php
$to = $form_values['submitted_tree']['uw_gegevens']['e_mail'];
$from = "no-reply@example.com";
$achternaam = $form_values['submitted_tree']['uw_gegevens']['uw_naam'];


$message = drupal_mail('webform_extra', 'reply', $to, language_default(), array('body' => $body), $from, TRUE);

function webform_extra_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  $message['subject'] = "TEXT.";


  $message['body'] = "
TEXT, " . $params['achternaam'] . "
TEXT. 


KIND REGARDS,
TEXT
";


} ?>
```

Hope this helps

Guus van de Wal